# iphone how to connect a web page on clicking a button

Tags: iphone, xcode

I'm preparing a project in which I want to connect to an URL on clicking a button. I have prepared the database side, even TCP program prototype is ready in my mind but I cant open a page by clicking a button. Can you please help?

Answer (score 4):

Open a page, how?

If you want the page to open in Safari, you can do this:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://stackoverflow.com/"]];
```

If you want to open the page in an embedded browser in your app, you can use `UIWebView`.

If you only want to open an HTTP connection, take a look at `NSURLConnection`.

Comment: firstly thank you very much. my application will have a button, and when clicked on it willsend a request to statik ip(url). i just yesterday started iphone programming but i'm experienced in android..

Comment: @ilhançetin if it's an HTTP request, as I said, take a look at NSURLConnection. if you want a TCP connection (but not HTTP), take a look at CFNetwork.